# Sonarqube Lcov Coverage not getting displayed

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, lcov

I am using ReactJS and ran the `react-scripts test --ci --coverage` for code coverage testing. It created a folder called coverage and inside that i see `lcov.info` file.

I gave this path in the `sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPaths=XXX/coverage/lcov.info` in the `sonar-project.properties` and ran the scan. But still i couldn't see the coverage report.

Am i missing something here.

Thanks.

Comment: can you point out your logoutput, sonarqube scanners can be very verbose and give you a lot of information. based on your description it is really hard to give you hints.

Comment: Thanks for your response. May i know where to see the Code Coverage in the Sonar Server ???

Comment: on the project page you see the coverage, or do you mean in the logs?

Comment: which sonar scanner are you using? how do you trigger the sonarqube analysis?